# Error when ploting datetime data with matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, python-datetime

I am struggling with matplotlib to plot a curve based on data from sensors composed of a date (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) and a float. I have looked for information about how to plot datetime values and I am able to display them but the figure I get is not correct:

[Curve displayed with Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqH6i.png)

[Curve displayed with matplotlib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8NND.png)

Here is my code to display such figure (this script is a part of a FreeCAD add-in):

```
dates = matplotlib.dates.date2num(xData)
plt.plot_date(dates,yData)
plt.show()
```

xData  and yData are the lists of values extracted from the file DATA.txt: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/04fd9842a0beb0fd0e06666908b2562720200825135406/87b28f.

Any advise would be appreciated! Thx

Comment: Be sure to convert the dates to datetime and the floats to float. Strings are treated as categorical

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In deed the values I ploted were strings and not floats actulally.

Answer (score 0):

I use a text editor to replace the seperator with `,` like

```
0.13934599999999955,2020-07-12 15:31:11
0.1562399999999998,2020-07-12 15:24:07
0.20419800000000032,2020-07-12 15:16:52
0.0922520000000004,2020-07-12 15:02:33
0.19564400000000023,2020-07-12 14:55:30
0.14740400000000045,2020-07-12 14:48:15
```

Here goes the program:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("DATA.txt")

df.columns = ['Value', 'Date']
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

plt.plot(df['Date'], df['Value'])

plt.show()
```

[image]

You can use [Date formatters](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/dates_api.html#date-formatters) to change the format of xlabel. You can check the format code with [strftime.org](https://strftime.org/).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("DATA.txt")

df.columns = ['Value', 'Date']
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

plt.plot(df['Date'], df['Value'])

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%Y'))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

you must first import pandas and matplot

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

then you must open the data using pandas
ex `pd.read_csv("anything.csv")`

Comment: Yes I import properly the different library (I am using the library csv for csv data). I have checked what I have in xData and yData and the values are good.